# All pairs shortest paths in a DAG

Tags: graph-algorithms, directed-acyclic-graph, topological-graph-theory

I have studied the Floyd-Warshall and Johnson algorithms. I am trying to understand if the all pairs shortest paths research in a directed graph G can be implemented in a more efficient way if I already know that G is acyclic. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @R B is that the worst case running time? Can you also please tell me the source of what you state?

Comment: This can easily be solved in $O(VE)$ with dynamic programming.

Comment: @Saeed: That won't work. Consider the case $V=\{v_0,v_1,v_2\}$ and $E=\{(v_0,v_1),(v_0,v_2),(v_1,v_2)\}$. Then $v_0$ is a source, and $d_1=d_2=1$, so $d_{1,2}=\infty$ (rather than $1$) according to your algorithm.

Comment: @KlausDraeger, Yes you are right.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate DAG-Shortest-Paths (in Cormen, Lesierson, Rivest, and Stein's text ["Introduction to Algorithms"](http://mitpress.mit.edu/books/introduction-algorithms)).

Comment: Such algorithm would have teta (|V|^3) running time in the worst case, not better than Floyd-Warshall and Johnson.

Comment: Why do you say that?  DAG-shortest paths runs in V+E, due to the topological sort that does not necessarily have to be repeated.

Comment: Do you know a mechanism to determine which vertices and in which order to give in input to DAG-shortest-paths?

Comment: Any order at all.